# Android Activity Testing issues linking classes

Tags: android, junit

I have a simple Android Project and a simple Android Test Project.  My goal is to test the activities of my Android Project.  I should note, that I'm using appcompat_v7.  I receive this error when running the android junit test:

```
Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/media/TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2;' failed 
Cannot load class. Make sure it is in your apk. Class name: 'android.support.v4.media.TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2'. Message: android.support.v4.media.TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2
```

Any suggestions?

**Test Project Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myandroidproject.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />

    <instrumentation
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="com.example.myandroidproject" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Testing Class:**

```
package com.example.myandroidproject.test;

import com.example.myandroidproject.MyAndroidActivity;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.util.Log;

public class TestingMyAndroidActivity extends
ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyAndroidActivity> {

    public TestingMyAndroidActivity() {
        super(MyAndroidActivity.class);
    }

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        Log.d("TAG", "setUp");
    }

    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
        Log.d("TAG", "tearDown");       
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the emulator/device you're running the unit tests on support that library.  I ran into this and realized i was using one of my Kindle emulators :(.